# How to check the XML tag string?

Tags: ios, iphone, xmppframework, nsxml

Hi I am working with the xml below is my xml from server.

```
 <message xmlns="jabber:client" to="91957@ip-148" id="A2EFL-1435" from="9176@ip-148"><x xmlns="jabber:x:event"><composing/><id>A2EFL-1434</id></x></message>
```

Now i need to check that whether xml having `composing` element or not.And I am not using any xml delegates. Is there any possibility with out using delegate methods for XML

```
 NSXMLElement *events = [message elementForName:@"x"];
    NSString *eventString=[[message elementForName:@"x"] stringValue];
    if (![eventString isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSString *composingString=[[events elementForName:@"composing"] stringValue];
        if ([composingString isEqualToString:@""]||[composingString isEqualToString:@"nil"]) {}
```

But i need to check that xml tag not value

Comment: But how to check that tag is equal to "composing" string i have different names for every xml

Comment: yes exactly i have different strings for every xml responce i need to check the string

Comment: How to convert the `NSXMLElement ` to `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it with string operations. Check for this.

```
NSRange rangeValue = [xmlString rangeOfString:@"<composing>" OR @"<composing/>" OR options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if (rangeValue.length > 0){

NSLog(@"Tag is present");

} 

else {

NSLog(@"Tag is not present");

}
```

Comment: ` NSXMLElement *events = [message elementForName:@"x"];
        NSString *xmlString=(NSString *)events;
        NSRange rangeValue = [xmlString rangeOfString:@"<composing>" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (rangeValue.length > 0){
            NSLog(@"composing Tag is present");
        }
`

Comment: When i use above code it is getting error like unrecogned

Comment: Got it Thanks its working fine.But is their any other way to check the XML elements.

Comment: The only option is to parse the XML.

Comment: Okay Thanks for your efforts.